# This RISC-V Code that does not halt due to some problem in free syscall in Venus simulator

Tags: assembly, riscv

Here is my simple RISC-V code that I have written after isolating the problem associated with larger code.

```
.globl main

# we have a0, a1, a2
main:
    addi sp, sp, -36
    sw s0, 0(sp)
    sw s1, 4(sp)
    sw s2, 8(sp)
    sw s3, 12(sp)
    sw s4, 16(sp)
    sw s5, 20(sp)
    sw s6, 24(sp)
    sw s7, 28(sp)
    sw s8, 32(sp)

    addi sp, sp, -24
    sw ra, 8(sp)
    sw a0, 12(sp)
    sw a1, 16(sp)
    sw a2, 20(sp)

    li a0, 4
    jal ra, malloc
    mv s0, a0

    lw ra, 8(sp)
    lw a0, 12(sp)
    lw a1, 16(sp)
    lw a2, 20(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 24

    # cleaning m0
    addi sp, sp, -16
    sw a0, 0(sp)
    sw a1, 4(sp)
    sw a2, 8(sp)    
    sw ra, 12(sp)
    
    mv a0, s0
    jal ra, free

    lw a0, 0(sp)
    lw a1, 4(sp)
    lw a2, 8(sp)
    lw ra, 12(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 16

    #Epilog
    lw s0, 0(sp)
    lw s1, 4(sp)
    lw s2, 8(sp)
    lw s3, 12(sp)
    lw s4, 16(sp)
    lw s5, 20(sp)
    lw s6, 24(sp)
    lw s7, 28(sp)
    lw s8, 32(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 36
    ret
    
free:
    mv a1 a0
    li a0 0x3CC
    addi a6 x0 4
    ecall
    ret


malloc:
    mv a1 a0
    li a0 0x3CC
    addi a6 x0 1
    ecall
    ret
```

This code does not halt. However, when I comment out the code that calls to free the code works fine.

The code snippet for malloc and free is taken from [Berkeley's cs61C fa2020 project 2](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61c/fa20/projects/proj2/#task-3-putting-it-all-together).

I have tried running the code using Venus simulator.